# ANOVA Error in levels(x)[x]

Tags: r, statistics

I am attempting to run an ANOVA on some data, but it gives me the following error:

```
Call:
   aov(formula = speaker ~ CoG * skewness * kurtosis, data = total)
Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type="numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : - not meaningful for factors
```

I'm trying to see how well the three variables CoG, skewness and kurtosis can predict the speaker and if they are significant between speakers. A copy of my data an be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/blzpb12bemv6kuc/All.csv

Can anyone help interpret what the error is saying and where it is occurring?

Comment: Your response, `speaker` is a categorical variable, so an ANOVA doesn't make sense.  Did you mean to run on some other variable instead?

Comment: Oh... I want to find if each speaker is different based on CoG, skewness and Kurtosis. Someone told me an ANOVA could be used. Perhaps I should be using a different test?

Comment: To examine differences between speaker with regards to skewness, one might perform an ANOVA, but with the variables reversed: `skewness ~ speaker`. I think maybe you need more help with the basic statistics going on here than with an specific programming problem.

Comment: If you do need help with the basic statistics, try asking at stats.stackexchange.com.  Reference this question, but make it clear that you're asking about what kind of analysis would be appropriate, not about this error message.  Be sure to include enough background information both about your data and about the kinds of conclusions you want to make so that others can understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I gave on stats.stackexchange.com

Sounds like you are trying to do Multinomial regression. Perhaps look up information on that.

Here is a great start:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm

e.g.

```
install.packages('nnet')
library(nnet)

test<-multinom(formula = as.factor(speaker) ~ CoG * skewness * kurtosis, data = total)


z <- summary(test)$coefficients/summary(test)$standard.errors
# 2-tailed z test
p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2
```